# Probability of a journey

Tags: probability

A trip from south east London to Southampton consists of three journeys: bus journey to Crystal Palace station, train journey from Crystal Palace to Clapham Junction, train journey from Clapham Junction to Southampton. Each journey can be delayed (d) or on time (o) with the following probabilities:

For the bus journey to Crystal Palace station: P(d)=2/3 and P(o)=1/3

For the train journey from Crystal Palace to Clapham Junction: P(d)=1/4 and P(o)=3/4

For the train journey from Clapham Junction to Southampton: P(d)=1/4 and P(o)=3/4 The lateness or not of any transport is independent of the lateness or not of any other transport.

Consider the following two events: 
A={delays in the trip are due only to delays in the bus journey}
B={delays in the trip are due to delays in one or both of the train journeys} 
Calculate the probabilities P(A), P(B).

Attempting this question:
I created a sample space where 
S = {OOO, OOD, ODO, ODD, DDD, DOO, DOD, DDD}

P(A) = DOO
2/3*3/4*3/4 =3/8

P(B) = OOD, ODO, ODD, 
1/3 * 3/4 * 1/4 + 1/3 * 1/4 * 3/4 + 1/3 * 1/4 * 1/4 = 7/48

Is this correct? 
Also, if the probabilities were not independent how would I calculate the probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  If the probabilities were not independent, they would have to tell you how the chance a train is late changes with whether the bus is late.  You would have to use the proper chance for the train being late in each of your multiplications.